# can't pass complete text

Tags: django, django-templates

```
<span>Question:<input type=text value={{QuestionText}} id="question">
```

Say the text in QuestionText is `HOW YOU DOING` (note that there is no quotes), but the actual output is the text box filled with only `HOW` part without the following. How can I get the whole text in the input box?  Thank you

Comment: as dgel says, if there are no quotes, only the first word will appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put quotations to make it look like this:

```
<span>Question:<input type=text value="{{QuestionText}}" id="question">
```

Without the quotes, it's only the first word that gets assigned to your value attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes:

```
<span>Question:<input type="text" value="{{QuestionText}}" id="question">
```